# Run the same for loop (different iterations) at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, loops, for-loop

I'm a total beginner at Python and am currently running this webscraping program to scrape for several Excel files for thousands of observations in my dataset. The problem is is that it runs SO slow--I have 33k+ observations, of which I've only completed about 160 iterations so far over about 12 hours. This isn't feasible, obviously, so I was wondering how to scale this process up so that it will run 3, 5, or even 10 iterations at ONCE rather than one iteration at a time.

I am looking for a **quick fix** and can't seem to find anything on the internet. Here's my for loop ("commid" is what I'm iterating over--an array of codes to search on a particular website):

```
for i in range(0, 33312):
    
    #Say what iteration this is
    print('Beginning iteration')
    print(i)


    #Calling to use Chrome to webscrape
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
    
    #Create WebDriverWait times of 5, 10, 15 and 30 seconds
    wait5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    wait10 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait15 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    wait30 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    
    #Open FEC webpage; add "data/committee/C00716720" at end of link if want to test on Hickenlooper
    driver.get("https://www.fec.gov/")
    
    

    #Find the searchbar and search the PCC ID
    searchbar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header[2]/div/ul/li[3]/form/div/span/input')
    searchbar.send_keys(commid[i])
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        
    
    #Click on PCC Homepage
    pcc = wait5.until(
      EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/ul/li/h3/a'))
      )
    pcc.click()
        
    
    try:
        
        #Get Two-Year election cycle Period drop down menu in PCC Homepage
        select = driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='summary-cycle']")  #get the select element            
        options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list
        
    except:
        pass
    
    else:
        
        #Create array that will hold all election cycle options for PCC 'i'
        optionsList = []
        
        for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in the options array
            optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
        
        #Now, for each PCC in the dataset, loop over all available election cycles each PCC was registered for
        for oppy in optionsList:
            
          
            #Select the election cycle of interest
            dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('summary-cycle'))
            dropdown.select_by_value(oppy)
            sleep(randint(5,7))
            
    
        
            try: 
                
            #Clicks on "Browse receipts" button on PCC i's homepage
                receipts = wait10.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="total-raised"]/div[1]/a')))
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",receipts)
                   
                sleep(randint(10,15))
            
                
            except:
                
                if NoSuchElementException:
                   
                    try:
                        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[2]/header/div/span[3]')
                        print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                        #print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(comm5[i])))
                        print('Receipts do not exist for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))    
                        pass
                    
                    except:
                        print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                        print('Webpage does not exist for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))
                        driver.back()
          
                    
            else:
                
                try:
                    #Clicks on "Export" button for receipts from succeeding webpage of receipt data
                    receiptsexport = wait15.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button')))
                    receiptsexport.click()
                    sleep(randint(5,7))
                
                except:
                    print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                    #print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(comm5[i])))
                    print('There is no Receipt Data to export for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))    
                    sleep(randint(5,7)) 
                    pass
                     
                else: 
                    
                    try:
                        
                        #Clicks on "Download" button under "Your downloads" to download receipts as .csv file
                        receiptsdownload = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/ul/li/div/a')))
                        sleep(randint(5,7))
                        receiptsdownload.click()
                        sleep(randint(5,7))
                        driver.back()
                        sleep(randint(5,7)) 
                    
                    except:
                        print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                        print('I cannot download Receipt Data, since there is none to export for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))
                        driver.back() #Go back to PCC homepage
                        sleep(randint(5,7))
                        pass
                    
            
            try:
              
                #Search for "Browse Disbursements" on PCC i's homepage and click link
                disburse = wait10.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Browse disbursements")))
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",disburse)
                
                sleep(randint(10,15))
            
            except:
                print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                #print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(comm5)))
                print('Disbursements do not exist for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))    
                sleep(randint(5,7)) 
                pass
            
            else:
                
                try:
                    
                    #Clicks on "Export" button for disbursements from succeeding webpage of disbursement data
                    disbursexport = wait15.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button')))
                    disbursexport.click()
                    
                    sleep(randint(5,7))
                
                except:
                    print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                    #print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(comm5)))
                    print('There is no Disbursement Data to export for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))    
                    sleep(randint(5,7)) 
                    pass
                     
                else: 
                    
                    try:
                        #Clicks on "Download" button under "Your downloads" to download disbursements as .csv file
                        disbursedownload = wait15.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/ul/li/div/a')))
                        sleep(randint(5,7))
                        disbursedownload.click()
                        driver.back()
                        sleep(randint(5,7)) 
                        
                        
                    except:
                        print('For PCC ID {},'.format(''.join(commid[i])))
                        print('I cannot download Disbursement Data, since there is none to export for election year {}.'.format(''.join(oppy)))
                        driver.back() #Go back to PCC homepage
                        sleep(randint(5,7))
                        pass
```

Comment: Look into threads. Also are all those sleeps necessary that's a lot of extra time wasted.

Comment: Resetting the driver also takes some time as well now.

Comment: I read online to use the sleeps (some are necessary to let the page load) to prevent the website from banning your IP haha

Comment: Simplify the question : we are not to read so many lines of code.

Comment: 1/ Put out of the loop every thing you can mainly webdriver init 2/ Better : do not use this library put a simpler one

Comment: first create function which do it for single URL - and later use `multiprocessing` to run every URL in separated process.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `driver = webdriver.Chrome(..)` before `for`-loop. You could also check if pages don't use JavaScript because if page doesn't use JavaScript then it is faster use `requests+beautifulsoup` or `scrapy` instead of `selenium`

Comment: hpchavez my question is extremely simple, the code length doesn't matter since I'm just asking to do multiple loops at once. Thanks everybody for the help! I'll try these approaches.